# If statement outputting multiple values, rather than one and breaking

Tags: python

So I'm trying to get an if statement to output a single string, but for some reason, it's outputting multiple? Trying something like 8 usually does this:

```
n = int(input('Enter a number: '))

W = print('Weird')
nW = print('Not Weird')

if (n % 2) == 0:
    if n == range(2, 5):
        nW
    elif n == range(6,20):
        W
    elif n > 20:
        nW
elif (n % 2) != 0:
    nW
else:
    print('Invalid Input')
```

Example input and output:

```
Enter a number: 8
Weird
Not Weird
```

I only want it to output one string, based on conditions met within the two if statements. Any idea what I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be under the misapprehension that: W = print('Weird') will not print. You need to go back to the documentation on print().

Comment: You seem to have a misconception. From the way your code is written, it looks like you expect every instance of `nW` and `W` to invoke the respective calls to `print` which you 'bound' above. That's not how it works. What you're actually doing is printing two strings ("Weird" and "Not Weird"), and then binding the return value of `print` (which is `None`) to those variables. You'll have to use separate `print`s on the actual lines where you want printing to take place. You can't just bind entire executable Python snippets to a variable, and then expect it to work.

Comment: @user10987432 You could post that as an answer and I would upvote it

Comment: I'm voting to close this, I can't really see it being useful in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
W = print('Weird')
nW = print('Not Weird')
```

These lines will *cause printing to happen immediately*, and assign the *value that `print` returns* (the special value `None`) to each of `W` and `nW`.

```
if n == range(2, 5):
    nW
```

This (similarly for the other lines that just have W or nW by themselves) will *not* cause `print` to be called. They will check what the current value of `nW` (or `W`) is, and then *ignore that value* - in much the same way that if you wrote `1 + 2` on a line by itself in the middle of your program, it would compute `3` and then do nothing with that `3` result.

If you want to "alias" a function call like this, you have some options: you can define your own simpler function explicitly, for example

```
def W():
    print('Weird')
```

or you can use e.g. `functools.partial` from the standard library to "bind" parameters to the call:

```
import functools

W = functools.partial(print, 'Weird')
# Now W is a special object that represents calling `print` and passing `'Weird'` to it
```

But in any of these cases you will *still need to call the function*: `W()`, not `W`.

The more reasonable approach is to give names to *the messages you want to print*, and then print them at the appropriate times:

```
W = 'Weird'
# and later you can just
print(W)
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes so much sense! 

I really didn't realize that print would do that, although a friend mentioned you couldn't assign print to a variable. 

Thank you so much again! I think I'm going to use 

```
w = 'Weird'

print(w)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're expecting `W = print('Weird')` to bind the **expression** `print('Weird')` to the name `W`, but that's not how it works. It actually calls `print('Weird')`, which prints `Weird`, then binds the **return value**, `None`, to `W`.

One way to fix it is define `W` and `nW` as strings, then print them.

```
W = 'Weird'
...
print(W)
```